# How to Practically Split Values from CSV File into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

Let's suppose I have the following line in a CSV file (I removed the header row in this example):

```
"500,000",2,50,2,90000
```

I have a PHP script read the CSV file, break the file into individual lines, and store each line in an array called $linearray. Then, I use a foreach loop to look at each line individually.

Within the foreach loop, I break the line into separate variables using the following function:

```
$line = str_replace("'","\'",$line);
```

From here, I insert the values into separate columns within a MySQL database. The script works. The values are inserted into a database, but I run into a problem. I want:

```
"500,000"  |  2  |  50  |  2  |  90000
```

But I get this:

```
"500  |  000"  |  2  |  50  |  2  |  90000
```

The script isn't smart enough to understand it should skip commas within quotation marks. Do you know how I can alter my script to make sure I get the output I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) function

`print_r(str_getcsv($line));`

**Outputs:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 500,000
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 90000
)
```

> Similar to [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) this functions parses a string as its input unlike [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/fgetcsv) which takes a file as its input.

Comment: Note that str_getcsv only works in PHP 5.3 and above. For earlier versions, "save" the string to the php://memory special file and use fgetcsv to parse it. Not that str_getcsv is really relevant to this question since the OP specifically have a file, so reading it one line at a time probably makes sense.

Comment: @Emil Yeah, I was just showing him an example using the `$line` variable he already had. At the bottom I stated what he should do for a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Try [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv).